# how to check crypted passwords against plaintext passwords stored in a file (.lst)?

Tags: python, crypt

Been checking around on how i can validate crypted passwords against plaintext passwords which are stored in a file on my Desktop named pswd0.lst. I want to check if a password named 'test3' can be found in the file if i give the hashed version of it, in this case it's `oHZcndn1xmAvs`. Anyone who can help?

````
import os, sys
import getopt
import crypt

def checkPassword(pswd, cpswd):
    """ Check if `cpwsd` an encrypted version is of `pswd`.
        Return `True` or `False`
    """
    try:
        cryptedpass = crypt.crypt(pswd, cpswd) == cpswd
        return cryptedpass
    except KeyError:
        return 0  # no match

def readPasswordList(fname):
    """ Read the passwords of the file named by 'fname'.
        Return `list or strings`, the password-list
    """
    file = open(fname, 'r')
    data = file.read()
    return data

def checkPasswords(cpswd, fname):
    """ Check crypted `cpswd` against the passwords of the file named by `fname`.
        Return `string` or None, password if found.
    """
    file = open(fname, 'r')
    data = file.read()
    passw = crypt.crypt(data, cpswd) == data
    return passw


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = ''
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'Vf:', [])
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-f': fname = arg
    if len(args) != 1:
        print('Usage: {} [-v] [-f <fname>] <cpswd>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(0)

    cpswd = args[0]
    pswd = checkPasswords(cpswd, fname)
    if pswd:
        print("Pass for '{}' is '{}'".format(
            cpswd, fname))
    else:
        print("Pass for '{}' not found".format(
            cpswd, fname))```
````

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the problem? Error? - post error.log. Program does not work as expected? - post expected output and actual output. Please see [ask] and [mre]

Comment: There is no error, it just says the hash oHZcndn1xmAvs cannot find any passwords in my file, while it actually should because it is 'test3'. Can't seem to find how to let it read the file and validate the given hash.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two problems:

1. When you read the files, you read the entire file as one long string. You don't split it into individual lines.
2. You are forgetting that crypt() function adds a salt, so two crypt() functions will produce different results for the same password.

I googled "python crypt" and, voila, the first result: https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html